# macOS: Disable popup showing accented characters when holding down a key

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

How do I disable the display of popup which appears when holding down a key? It slows my typing speed and makes me do so many mistakes in my writing and programming. I need it at time when I wish to enter an alphabet twice.

[image]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In macOS, when a key is held down while entering text, a popup is shown which lets one choose between various accented forms of the character. To disable this execute the following command line in the Terminal.app:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Now, you'll need to log out and log back in. This should disable the display of the popup and character typed should start repeating when the key is held down.

If you ever wish to return to this behaviour, execute the following command line in the Terminal.app:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

You'll need to log out and log back in again for the setting to take effect.

Comment: thank you! i have a problem in Intellij products because of this feature: after I press and hold some letter button on a keyboard, any code editor pane is disabled for text input. now, the problem fixed. thank you again.

Comment: Is there a way to map holding the letter onto a specif one of the popup items?

Comment: @JoelH I am not aware of any built-in way. It may be possible with the help of a 3rd-party tool.

Comment: Note: you don't seem to have to log out and back in, just restart any apps where it doesn't take effect immediately (some seem to not need to be restarted at all).

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this should be an option in the Keyboard settings, but Apple is Apple I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by turning my keyboard off and then on, and the special chars window went away; now it only shows if I press and hold a key for a few seconds (like it should); before, it was showing every time and there was no way for me to remove it.

My guess is that a keyboard key got stuck sending the pressed signal or something like that.

Comment: This is not a bug, it's a feature.