# Alternative shortcuts to create umlauts with US keyboard, for example, Option+o for ö

Tags: keyboard

I have an Macbook Pro 2020 (macOS Monterey) with a Touch Bar Keyboard (US layout).

I would like to type German umlauts easily, e.g., via pressing <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to get ö. However, I'm always only getting ø.

Any idea how I can change that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Option+key isn't creating the wrong umlauts, it's just the way the US keyboard is configured to work on macOS. I've changed the title to make it clear that you wish alternative key shortcuts to create umlauts.

Comment: @jaume - I think your edit has changed the intent of the post. That is not the same question as the OP asked. The OP was proposing a solution which was really an XY problem. You've re-emphasised the XY aspect of it & not allowed for a frame challenge.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think this is a XY problem. As someone who uses a US keyboard and writes lots of German on a daily basis, the OP's wish makes sense. I don't think my edit has changed the intent of the post, either: **the perceived cumbersomeness of a key shortcut doesn't make it wrong**. That's the only bit I've changed, and the new title doesn't preclude anyone from proposing an alternative solution (note the use of _for example_).

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses dead keys to get to the most common accent types.
The key command for each accent is always the same, the letter you type next determines the outcome.

[image]
[image]

From these images you can see that the umlaut is on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd> 
so to achieve ö you type  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  then  <kbd>O</kbd> 
To get ü you type  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  then  <kbd>U</kbd>  and similar for any letter that will take an umlaut

The same applies for the other accents.

This applies to all English layouts, US & International. Other languages where accents are more common tend to have their own specific keyboards & layouts to bring some of the more common ones forwards.

There is also a structure called Press & Hold, where if you hold any key down for a second or so, a pop-up will appear with more accent variations than can be achieved by this method.

[image]

If you really want to change what the option key does, you can make a custom layout with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Comment: thanks for your reply. How can I enable press & hold please?

Comment: @Gloria  Press and Hold should be enabled by default for the last 10 years or so.  Do you just get repeated a's if you hold down the a key?

Comment: If you somehow disabled it, [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/332770/207895) is how you enable Press and Hold again.